# VHDL trouble to initate 2D array with 0

Tags: vhdl

I have a trouble to initiate a 2D array with '0' in VHDL.

I try to used the key word "others" as a 1D array:

```
type F_type is array (0 to f_deep-1) of std_logic_vector(f_wLgth-1 downto 0);   
signal FIFO : F_type := ((others => (others => '0')));
```

but when i try to compile on Quartus 17.1.0, I'm always having the same error message:

> Error (276000): Cannot synthesize initialized RAM logic "spi_DAC:s_dac|FIFO:fifo_c|FIFO"

Thank for reading.

Best Aldarme

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer.

QUARTUS try to store 2D array into RAM FPGA RAM bloc.
But it's complexe (more than "(others => (others => '0'))") to initiate the all elements of the array.

So we have to define the 2D array as following:

signal myArray: F_type;

At t=0, the all element will be at 'U'.
We have to initiate the first case of the array with a valid data.
In other case, if we try to read 'U', we will have the propagation of the element 'X'.

Best